# Combine CompletableStage dynamically with eventually error propagation

Tags: java, completable-future

I need to combine `CompletionStages` dynamically (based on computation results) in order to not blocking the execution and eventually I need to capture the exceptions that could arise during the operations in order to shutdown carefully the execution.

I have implemented something like the following:

```java
public CompletableFuture<Data> getData() {

    final Data accumulator = new Data();

    CompletableFuture<Data> result = new CompletableFuture<>();

    CompletableStage exec = ... //starting execution

    exec.thenComposeAsync(
                    (res) -> process(accumulator, res)
            ).thenAccept(t -> result.complete(accumulator));
    return result;
  }

  private CompletionStage<Void> process(Data acc, Result res) {

    res.data().forEach(
            currData -> {
              add.addData(currData);
            }
    );
    if (res.hasMoreData()) {
      return res.fetchNextData().thenComposeAsync(
              (nextData) -> process(acc, nextData)
      );
    }

    return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(null);

  }
```

I don't know if that is the best way to implement the solution but it works if all is fine. The problems come when an exception arises in `forEach` block for any reason, the error is not propagated back to `getData` caller so I can't catch it with `exceptionally` method in order to stop my application in a safe way. I suppose that I am doing something wrong.

Comment: the code reported is only a snippet to show what I trying to do and which is the problem. the code will not compile because most of the parts are missing.

Comment: I'm confused as to what you're trying to do. But I did notice your "it works if all is fine".

Comment: I don't know if my solution is correct. It works well when all goes fine. My problem is related to exceptions. When an exception occurs in the `forEach` i am not able to catch it on caller of `getData`.

Comment: @Holger you are right. I am sorry. I have adapted the code from my source. I can't expose the entire source code. Now should be better.

Comment: @Scratte I will try to make the example runnable.

Comment: @Holger Your solution is useful. Why not put it in an Answer?

Comment: @Holger your last solution works very well.

Comment: @Scratte I made it an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the function passed to `thenComposeAsync` fails with an exception, the future returned by `thenComposeAsync` will be completed exceptionally. This causes the futures created by chained ordinary operations to complete exceptionally as well, without evaluating their functions.

There are three exceptions to the rule, [`exceptionally`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletionStage.html#exceptionally-java.util.function.Function-), which is only evaluated after an exceptional completion, to produce a replacement value, whereas [`handle`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletionStage.html#handle-java.util.function.BiFunction-) and [`whenComplete`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletionStage.html#whenComplete-java.util.function.BiConsumer-) are evaluated in either case.

So when you want to replace exceptions with a fallback value, you can use

```
exec.thenComposeAsync(res -> process(accumulator, res))
    .exceptionally(throwable -> fallBack)
    .thenAccept(t -> result.complete(accumulator));
```

Care must be taken to chain `exceptionally` before `thenAccept`, as otherwise the function passed to `thenAccept` would not get evaluated in the exceptional case.

When you want to propagate the exception to the `result` future, you can use

```
exec.thenComposeAsync(res -> process(accumulator, res))
    .whenComplete((value, throwable) -> {
         if(throwable == null) result.complete(accumulator);
         else result.completeExceptionally(throwable);
    });
```

It’s crucial to check the `throwable` against `null` to determine whether the completion was exceptional, as the `value` can be `null` as an ordinary result. Even in a scenario where the ordinary result value can never be `null`, it’s recommended to stick to the idiomatic solution, as you don’t know whether and when you will reuse the code.